# Finding object in a class by attribute value

Tags: class, object, lua

How do you grab an object based on its attribute (in this case, an ID that is assigned to it)? Here is an example of the code that I'm currently working on.

```
Ped = {} -- Ped class.
Ped.__index = Ped
gPedID = 0
gPedAdditionalID = "Shop"

function Ped.create(_type, _skin, _x, _y, _z)
   local _ped = {}             
   setmetatable(_ped,Ped)  
   _ped.oType = _type 
   _ped.pedElement = createPed(_skin, _x, _y, _z)
   _ped.ID = gPedID
   gPedID = gPedID + 1
   return _ped
end

function pedID(player, command)
    -- code to grab the object based on the object.ID 
end
```

I've tried to make a table that references the object, i.e:

```
generictable[_ped.ID] = _ped
```

But to no avail, I'm guessing the reason why is because it only copies the address, not the actual reference.

Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `generictable[gPed.ID]` - don't you mean either `gPedID` or `_ped.ID`?

Comment: How do you populate the `generictable`? If you populate with objects based on unique IDs, such as `gPedID`, then `generictable[gPedID]` should return the particular entry (object for your case) with the ID.

Comment: `code`_ped.ID`code` is correct, also I populate it as shown in the example but what happens is it gives me an error every time I try to access the attributes of the `code`ped`code` object. So if I do

Comment: `code`generictable[correctID].pedElement == x `code` for example, it would give me an error that pedElement is a nil value.

Comment: Your idea was correct, you'll need to store them all in an easy to index way, please update your code with an example of the table not working.